# add hyperlink in v-data-table Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've been slowly learning the joys of vue.js and Vuetify.
I'm trying to get the emails and website as working links but just can't figure out how to do it.

I have my v-data-table

```
 <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="companies" :search.sync="search" :items-per-page="5">
```

In my script I'm having first:

```
    data: () => ({
    headers: [
      { text: "Bedrijfsnaam", align: "start", value: "name" },
      { text: "Telefoon", value: "phone" },
      { text: "e-Mail", value: "email" },
      { text: "Website", value: "website" },
      { text: "Locatie", value: "location" },
      { text: "Actions", value: "actions", sortable: false }
    ],
    companies: [],
  }),
```

And finally

```
  methods: {
    initialize() {
      this.companies = [
        {
          name: "Lorem NV",
          phone: "+32 1 234 56 78",
          email: "info@lorem.be",
          website: "www.lorem.be",
          location: "Gent"
        },
      ];
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`item.<name>` slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#api). For example, where `website` is the property name:

```
    <template #item.website="{ value }">
        <a :href="value">
          {{ value }}
        </a>
    </template>
```

OR `email`,

```
    <template #item.email="{ value }">
        <a :href="`mailto:${value}`">
          {{ value }}
        </a>
    </template>
```

This only needs to be used for the fields you want to customize.

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/CX3vXv6x6R

Answer (score 17):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You need to implement a custom template for the row that has the link:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="companies"
  :search.sync="search"
  :items-per-page="5"
>
  <template #item.phone="{ item }">
    <a target="_blank" :href="`tel:${item.phone}`">
      {{ item.phone }}
    </a>
  </template>
  <template #item.email="{ item }">
    <a target="_blank" :href="`mailto:${item.email}`">
      {{ item.email }}
    </a>
  </template>
  <template #item.website="{ item }">
    <a target="_blank" :href="item.website">
      {{ item.website }}
    </a>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

You can put whatever content inside of the `<template>` elements that you want, so, for example, if you had an `id` field for each company and you wanted to link the company name to the page within your website that has the details page about that company, you could do:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="companies"
  :search.sync="search"
  :items-per-page="5"
>
  <template #item.name="{ item }">
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'company', params: { id: item.id } }">
      {{ item.name }}
    </router-link>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

You can put buttons, icons, or whatever you want inside of the template. Hope this helps!